# can't unbind device in privileged lxc container

Tags: lxc

I am running privileged lxc 2.0 container on Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS.
I changed the `common.config` file to mount `sys` as read-writable:

I changed original mount entry `lxc.mount.auto = cgroup:mixed proc:mixed sys:mixed` to `lxc.mount.auto = cgroup:mixed proc:mixed sys:rw` so that `/sys/` is writable.

But when I try to unbind a device using:

```
 echo "0003:2965:5023.0004" > unbind (inside /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-multitouch)
bash: unbind: Permission denied
```

Looks like `/sys/` is not writable.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was using Ubuntu here and `AppArmor` was configured on the system, therefore the issue.

In `lxc` configuration file `/usr/share/lxc/config/ubuntu.common.conf`, following is commented. Uncomment the last line.

```
# When using LXC with apparmor, the container will be confined by default.
# If you wish for it to instead run unconfined, copy the following line
# (uncommented) to the container's configuration file.
lxc.aa_profile = unconfined ( ***** UNCOMMENT THIS LINE ******************** )
```